# Compare Two Dictionaries and Print Difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I have taken the difference between values for two dictionaries. What I have currently works, but I want to print "dict1[x] - dict2[x]" to the file I write to in front of the results. Not just the results. How can I do this? Do I need a nested loop?

```
comparison = {x: dict1[x] - dict2[x] for x in dict1 if x in dict2}

file1 = open('Results.txt', 'w')
for key,value in comparison.iteritems():
    print >> file1, ('%s: %s' % (key,value)) 
file1.close()
```

Edit: example

The values stored in each dictionary are timestamps, so I want my final results to look like:

```
12:30-11:30 = 1:00
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by `I want to print "dict1[x] - dict2[x]" to the file I write to in front of the results`. Can you updated your question with sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a tuple of `dict1[x]` and `dict2[x]` the key of the dict instead, and unpack accordingly when iterating over the dict items:

```
comparison = {(dict1[x], dict2[x]): dict1[x] - dict2[x] for x in dict1 if x in dict2}

file1 = open('Results.txt', 'w')
for (time1, time2), value in comparison.iteritems():
    print >> file1, ('%s-%s: %s' % (time1, time2, value)) 
file1.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible to then also include the key? For example, `key: time1 - time2 = value`